# componentDidUpdate - What am i doing wrong?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, redux

I am trying to bring the error messages from the backend to the frontend using the MERN stack. I am able to receive the error messages in the developer tools, but not able to show the messages in the UI. I am using Redux for the state manager. The console.log() in my concomponentDidUpdate is not working when I am submitting the form. Can someone please clarify what is wrong with my code?

```js
state = {
        name: '',
        email: '',
        phoneNo: null,
        dateOfBirth: new Date,
        gender: 'Select',
        education: '',
        checkBox: false,
        msg: null
    }

    static propTypes = {
        addInfo: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        info: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        error: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, nextProps) {
        const { error } = this.props;

        if (error !== nextProps.error) {
            console.log("Working");
            if (error.id === 'REGISTER_FAIL')
                this.setState({ msg: error.msg.msg });
            else
                this.setState({ msg: null });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

componentDidUpdate() will not be invoked in initial mount and will only be called during component rerenders.

If you need it to be called in initial mount as well as subsequent updates, either duplicate it to componentDidMount or use static getDerivedStateFromProps

Comment: First of all, I am submitting a form, and when it catches an error it goes to the error state of the redux. So, it is not the initial mount. Can you think of something else?

Answer (score 0):

Following this docs, [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) receive 3 params: `prevProps`, `prevState` and `snapshot`.

In your code, you used it like the next `props`:

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, nextProps)
```

It should be something like:

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
    const { error } = this.props;

        // React will call didUpdate after component is updated
        // this.props is the nextProps.error as you trying to do
        if (error !== prevProps.error) {
            console.log("Working");
            if (error.id === 'REGISTER_FAIL')
                this.setState({ msg: error.msg.msg });
            else
                this.setState({ msg: null });
        }
}
```

Or you will want to use [UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops)

`UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){}`

Comment: This is not working either. Can you think of something else?